# optimal delegation model extension

Tags: microeconomics, model

for my seminar paper I need to extend the model of optimal delegation, I have no idea how I can evaluate my ideas (because my professor keeps ignoring me) , can someone say if the idea of the variability of the state being reported decreasing with time (because the agent reveals more information) is a good idea ?
also does the adaptation of the model to some specific type of delegation can be considered its extension?
thanks!